# Как удалить вирусное расширение?

Tags: google-chrome, безопасность

Как удалить вирусное расширение в Хроме? Переустанавливала браузер, не помогло.

Comment: спасибо)но я так сто раз удаляла, оно возвращается

Comment: И не забудьте пожаловаться на вредоноса в службу поддержки гугла.

Comment: Данный вопрос не имеет отношения к программированию или системному администрированию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте перейти по ссылке: chrome://extensions
После, найдите это расширение и нажмите на корзину (удалить), с правой стороны, от расширения.

Answer (score 8):

В случае, если на ваш браузер было установлено вредоносное расширение, попробуйте следующее:

1. Удалить расширение в менеджере расширений браузера. Если
   злоумышленники рассчитывали на вашу невнимательность, этого может
   оказаться достаточно.
2. Если вы уже пробовали этот способ, но расширение появлялось вновь,
   то  браузер пока **не запускайте**. Если браузер автоматически
   перезапустился после удаления расширения, проверьте, **удалилось ли
   оно**. Если **да**, закройте браузер и переходите к п. 3, **иначе** -
   к п. 6.
3. Откройте свойства ярлыка, которым вы, обычно, запускаете ваш
   браузер. Если в пути к исполняемому файлу, после его названия, вы
   видите какие-либо подозрительные директивы (начинаются с `-` или
   `--`) - удалите их. Как вариант - просто удалите этот ярлык и
   создайте новый (в контекстном меню исполняемого файла выберите
   "создать ярлык", затем копируйте созданный ярлык в директорию,
   из которой удалили старый).
4. Запустите ваш браузер и проверьте, **появилось ли** вредоносное
   расширение. Если **нет** - закройте браузер и переходите к п. 5,
   **иначе** - к п. 6.
5. Перезапустите ваш компьютер и снова откройте браузер. **Если
   вредоносного расширения нет**, значит **вы победили**, **иначе** -
   проверьте настройки автозапуска вашей системы: скорее всего, там 
   висит вредоносный скрипт, при каждом запуске компьютера заново 
   устанавливающий расширение в ваш браузер. Если найдёте что-то
   похожее (или что-то, чего ни вы, ни система туда точно не ставили) -
   удалите и возвращайтесь к п. 1.
6. Если всё вышеописанное не помогло, **запустите систему в безопасном
   режиме** и вернитесь к п. 1. В п. 5 также используйте безопасный
   режим. Если в безопасном режиме проблему устранить **удалось**, значит
   на вашем компьютере установлена вредоносная **служба**, отменяющая
   все ваши действия, по удалению расширения. Вернитесь в обычный
   режим, найдите её в списке служб и удалите. Если не можете вычислить
   ту самую службу, - просто **отключите их все**, кроме системных и
   известных вам. Затем возвращайтесь к п. 1
7. Если все предыдущие шесть пунктов не принесли результата - вы вряд
   ли сможете решить проблему самостоятельно. Установите **firewall**,
   настройте его блокировать всю не разрешённую вами активность (режим
   белого списка) и **проверьте компьютер антивирусом**. Снова повторите
   пп. 1-5, если ещё есть, что устранять. Если не помогло даже это - мои
   соболезнования. Вызывайте специалиста или переустанавливайте всю
   систему: Помочь вам удалённо здесь уже вряд ли смогут.